# Google Maps Api - Deleting marker with mouseclick

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I got a problem with deleting a marker on mouse click. Well, the thing isnt as simple as it seems.

```
function addPoint(event) {
path.insertAt(path.length, event.latLng);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: event.latLng,
  map: map
});
markers.push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  marker.setMap(null);
  markers.splice(i, 1);
  }
);
```

If i used that code, adding listener right away when creating marker, deleting it would be easy, cuz i refer to `marker.setMap(null);`. But in my case i want them to be created, and then i want to add the event listener to them using

```
function usun(){
for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        alert('lol');
    });
}
```

I am pushing each marker to `markersArray` which lets me to add event to each of it now, but how can i delete it? When i put `marker.setMap(null);` in place of the alert, it says marker is not defined, and i dunno how can i refer to marker i just clicked :S
also cant use marker as global variable, cuz i am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined` error.

EDIT:
if i try using

```
function usun(){
for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++){
    google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function() {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    });
}
```

}
i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setMap' of undefined`. Thats why i was sure i need to use "marker".

Comment: This is a classical problem "closure in a loop". This is the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325736/creating-markers-in-loop-infowindow-does-not-open-when-inside-an-click-listene/8326203#8326203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop you are not referring to the marker that is in the array.

try this:

```
function usun(){
for (var i=0; i < markersArray.length; i++){

    google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function() {
        this.setMap(null);
    });

}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/52nJc/1/

Comment: Added "edit" in main post. I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setMap' of undefined` error, when try using that.

Comment: whoops sorry that was my bad copy paste error.  use `this` inside the listener.  Ill edit the post.

Comment: <3 thanks, accepting answer, if that means anything for ya :)