# creating markers in loop - Infowindow does not open when inside an click Listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have a google map with multiple markers and each has its own infowindow.

nothing happens when i click.  fyi: i know it the listener fires because i did put a alert in ther before and it worked.

Problem Code is:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(point[i], 'click', function() {
     infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString[i] });
     infowindow[i].open(map,point[i]);
});
```

if i only do

```
     infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString[i] });
     infowindow[i].open(map,point[i]);
```

it works. but not in my addListener function. i guess ther is something that googlemaps doesnt like but firebug gives me 0 errors..

really need your help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you probably have closure within loop! So the variable `i` in callback is already overwritten at the time when the callback is called. You have two options how to fix it:

1) classical "closure in loop" workaround (you do another closure for every loop iteration):

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { (function  (i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(point[i], 'click', function() {
         infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString[i] });
         infowindow[i].open(map,point[i]);
    });
})(i);
}
```

2) avoid closure and use the marker data structure:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    point[i].i = i;
    google.maps.event.addListener(point[i], 'click', function() {
         this.myinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString[this.i] });
         this.myinfowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

(or you could also move the contentString also to the marker: `point[i].contentString = ...` and use `this.contentString` in the click handler. Then you don't need the `point[i].i` attribute.)

Personally I much more prefer the 2nd solution over the first, since the closures consume memory etc.

Comment: This worked for me tonight in the same situation as the OP. Thanks Tomas (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and it has got something to do with the loop, because when I use hard coded values like this they do work:

```
                // Add infowindow
                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[0], 'click', function() {
                  infowindows[0].open(map,markers[0]);
                });
                // Add infowindow
                google.maps.event.addListener(markers[1], 'click', function() {
                  infowindows[1].open(map,markers[1]);
                });
```