# Close not a global InfoWindow created inside a loop when other InfoWindow appears

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, closures, infowindow

I'm having a messy situation here, hopes anybody can help me regarding the fact that this topic has been discussed in Stackoverflow.

I'm using a loop to read an XML and to create the markers based on the nodes of that XML, thats works. Also, inside that loop I call a function located ouside that loop to create an InfoWindow for every marker with content pulled from the XML.

- I create the InfoWindows outside the loop and inside a function because if I don't do that no matter in what marker I click it always show the same InfoWindows above the last added marker of the map.
- If I define InfoWindows global all the InfoWindows show the same content of the last created marker.

This is the code:

```
function xml_Leer() {       

    function agregar_datos(marcador, map, direccion, telefono, dias_habiles, sabado, domingo) {
        var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "<h2>"+nombre+"</h2><p>"+direccion+"</p><p>"+telefono+"</p><ul><li>Lunes a Viernes: "+dias_habiles+"</li><li>S&aacute;bados: "+sabado+"</li><li>Domingos: "+domingo+"</li></ul>"});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', function() {datos.open(map,marcador);});
    } 

    var iglesias = xml.getElementsByTagName("iglesia");

    for(var i=0; i<iglesias.length; i++) {
        var nombre = iglesias[i].getElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var direccion = iglesias[i].getElementsByTagName("direccion")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var telefono = iglesias[i].getElementsByTagName("telefono")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var dias_habiles = iglesias[i].getElementsByTagName("horarios")[0].getElementsByTagName("dias_habiles")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var sabado = iglesias[i].getElementsByTagName("horarios")[0].getElementsByTagName("sabado")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var domingo = iglesias[i].getElementsByTagName("horarios")[0].getElementsByTagName("domingo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        var tipo = iglesias[i].getAttribute("tipo");


        var ubicacion = new google.maps.LatLng(iglesias[i].getAttribute("lat"), iglesias[i].getAttribute("lng"));

        var marcador = new google.maps.Marker({position: ubicacion, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, map: map, title:nombre });

        agregar_datos(marcador, map, direccion, telefono, dias_habiles, sabado, domingo); 
    }

}
```

If this is not well coded, how I should create the InfoWindow taking into account that I need information taken from the XML to be displayed in the content of the InfoWindow?

Thanks in advance.

---

This code works, but I don't know how, just... works.

```
var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function agregar_datos(marcador, map, direccion, telefono, dias_habiles, sabado, domingo) {
    var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "<h2>"+nombre+"</h2><p>"+direccion+"</p><p>"+telefono+"</p><ul><li>Lunes a Viernes: "+dias_habiles+"</li><li>S&aacute;bados: "+sabado+"</li><li>Domingos: "+domingo+"</li></ul>"});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', function() { if(window.datos){window.datos.close();} window.datos=datos; datos.open(map,marcador);});
}
```

Comment: as I said: 'Create 1 global variable where you store the last opend infowindow. When you open a new infoWindow you may access this global variable and close the window',  that's what this code does. You don't need to set the global datos initially at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 1 global variable where you store the last opend infowindow. When you open a new infoWindow you may access this global variable and close the window:

**somewhere in global scope:**

```
var datos;
```

**in agregar_datos():**

remove the 2nd line and add this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', 
   function() {
     if(window.datos){window.datos.close();}
     window.datos=datos;
     datos.open(map,marcador);
});
```

---

Better solution: use only 1 infoWindow:

**somewhere in global scope:**

```
var datos=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

**in agregar_datos():**

remove the line :

```
var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow(/*....*/);
```

and add this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', 
       function() {
         window.datos.close();
         window.datos.setContent("put your content here");
         datos.open(map,marcador);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, already done that, but as I said in the question if I defined `datos` as global all the InfoWindows show the same content from the las marker created in the loop using the data from the XML. I try again with the code you write and the same thing happens.

Comment: Thanks again, I already saw and tried to implement the second solution, but my problem is that I can't generate the content of the InfoWindow "on the go", I must create the InfoWindow when I create the marker because it's when I access the specific node in the XML that content all the information about the marker (location and InfoWindow content), so only one InfoWindow that change the content with `setContent` implies that I must access the XML again and find the node somehow, again, and that's everytime a user click on a diferent marker, it's nos efficient process the XML everytime.

Comment: related to your first comment: definitly not, with my suggestion you have a local variable datos inside the function  agregar_datos, and a global variable which points to the last opened InfoWindow.

Comment: Aaaaahh, now I undestand you. You mean define var `datos=new google.maps.InfoWindow();` in global but maintaining the `var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "<h2>"+nombre+"</h2><p>"+direccion+"</p><p>"+telefono+"</p><ul><li>Lunes a Viernes: "+dias_habiles+"</li><li>S&aacute;bados: "+sabado+"</li><li>Domingos: "+domingo+"</li></ul>"});` inside the `agregar_datos` function?, well, that works. Thanks you, really, thanks you so much.

Comment: related to the 2nd: that's also not true, you must not access the xml again, you passed everything as arguments to the function

Comment: related to the 3rd: no, that's not what I meant

Comment: Yes, now I get it, I first thought I had to define `datos` as global and get rid of the local `datos` variable.

Comment: Haha, well, having `var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow();` as global and `var datos = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "<h2>"+nombre+"</h2><p>"+direccion+"</p><p>"+telefono+"</p><ul><li>Lunes a Viernes: "+dias_habiles+"</li><li>S&aacute;bados: "+sabado+"</li><li>Domingos: "+domingo+"</li></ul>"});` in local inside the function makes the InfoWindow hide when other appears. I don't know how. I also used your first modification to `google.maps.event.addListener`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because javascript closure issues, look here, it's the exact same issue!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8326203/684229

You have problem because when the marcador click event handler is launched, it uses `marcador` variable from the function call, but this has been already changed to the last marker in the for loop.

Just try to change your code in function `agregar_datos()` to use `this` instead of the `marcador`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'click', function() {datos.open(map, this);});
```

Comment: Using `this` doesn't change nothing. I saw that post and I tried to implement the solution you propose there but the user there use an array of markers, I guess because he didn't showed how he create the markers, and I don't, and I can't create an array of markers for use it inside the loop, I tried that in the first place.

Comment: I tried in the first place `var marcador[i] = new google.maps.Marker({position: ubicacion, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, map: map, title:nombre });`... doesn't work and that's why I ended up creating markers and InfoWindows like I show in the code.